# REST API endpoints not working in Vue + Flask app hosted on Apache

Tags: python, apache, vue.js, flask

I'm making a website for my university to display an Assyrian dictionary. I created the frontend in Vue and the backend in Flask, and I'm trying to get it working on the university's servers which are running Apache. Right now, my `app.py` just serves up the built `index.html` file I got from running `npm run build` on my Vue project as well as the other files it requests:

```py
from flask import Flask, send_file
from src.config import Config
import os

# Set up app
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='../dist/static')
app.config.from_object(Config)
DIST_DIR = app.config['DIST_DIR']

@app.route('/')
def index():
  entry = os.path.join(DIST_DIR, 'index.html')
  return send_file(entry)

@app.route('/api/endpoint')
def some_endpoint():
    return 'some JSON response'

# Catchall, for serving up CSS and JS requested by index.html
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def get_file(path):
  path = os.path.join(DIST_DIR, path)
  if os.path.exists(path):
    return send_file(path)
  else:
    # Fallback route for Vue router
    return send_file(os.path.join(DIST_DIR, 'index.html'))
```

Since I'm using Vue router, I changed my .htaccess file to have the following as directed by the docs (https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

My router is working fine, but the frontend tries to query /api/endpoint when it starts up and fails. It still just serves up `index.html`, but when I try this locally, it serves up 'some JSON response', as expected. Is there something I need to change in my .htaccess file? I'm not familiar with Apache at all and I'm not quite sure what that file is doing. It just seems to be ignorning the Python code and defaulting to the '/' route. How do I fix this?